# SharePoint 2010 - How to open New List Item Form as a new page?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, modal-dialog

I am developing an application on SharePoint 2010 and I would like to open **a New List Form as a new page, not a model dialog** from a simple a tag from a Content Editor Web part on a page:

```
<a onclick='javascript:NewItem2(event, "/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=8&amp;ListId={CC94D25C-2BE0-46AC-B8BE-F112D12F0907}&amp;RootFolder=");javascript:return false;' href="/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=8&amp;ListId={CC94D25C-2BE0-46AC-B8BE-F112D12F0907}&amp;RootFolder=" target=_blank>Create new item</a>
```

However, clicking this link opens invariably a model dialog. I precise that I selected 'No' for the Dialogs setting in the Advanced settings for my list.

Does anybody have a clue of what I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need onclick event to implement this. Just remove onclick attribute completely and leave href only.